# Why does a zombie process consume a large amount of CPU resources?

Tags: profiling, intel, zombie-process

`pcm-memory` was found to become a zombie process in the system, consuming a significant amount of CPU resources. At the same time, the `time` field in `top` will become abnormal: this machine only has a total of 56 logical cores, so it needs to run for at least 5124519h/56 = 91509h = 3812days, while the startup time of this machine is only 308 days

```
    PID    USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    799355 root      20   0       0      0      0 Z  4259  0.0  5124519h pcm-memory
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What OS?  I assume Linux, but what kernel version?  I wonder if a kernel bug resulted in corrupting the stats fields for that process.  (Or some kind of ABI mismatch between kernel and `top` or `ps` resulted in bad info from user-space tools?)  Also, this is `pcm-memory` from https://github.com/intel/pcm?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm using Linux 4.18.0, CentOS 7 and pcm-memory from Intel.